# Why wouldn't a shower hose/shower head come with a rubber washer?

Tags: shower, leak, hose

I have a shower sprayer in my shower.  There's the bracket that's attached to the shower arm and a hose attached to the bracket, with the sprayer on the other end of the hose.  I had put plumbers tape around all threaded parts to help it not leak.

My shower hose is 6 ft long if that matters.  For the past 4 years, there was no leaking but recently it started dripping from the bottom of the nut.  I unscrewed the nut, expecting to find a rotten rubber washer and get a replacement.  However, to my surprise, there was no rubber washer.  The leak I'm seeing is where the nut meets the hose (I can take a photo if I'm not clear enough).

I checked on the sprayer side and it too did not have a rubber washer, yet it was not leaking on the sprayer side.

I then went to Amazon and Home Depot to look at shower sprayers and shower hoses and it looked like most shower hoses and sprayers had rubber washers.  There might have been 1-2 that didn't.

I found [this link](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/how-to-install-a-showerhead.html) on installing a shower head and step 4 says:

> If your shower head did not come with a washer, skip this step. If it
> did come with a rubber washer, insert it into the shower arm
> connection nut and push it down flat.

So back to my initial question, why wouldn't a shower hose/sprayer/head come with a rubber washer?

EDIT: Here are some photos to hopefully demonstrate better what I'm trying to ask/describe.

This is a pic of the setup.  I pointed to where the drip/leak is coming from, which is at the bottom of the nut on the shower arm side.

[image]

Here are pictures of the hose after I've removed it.  As you can see, both ends have no rubber washer.  If I can re-use this hose by getting a replacement washer, I will.  But if the original design was to not need or use a washer, then I'll just toss it.

I tried to expose both ends of the hose to show what it looks like.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your sprayer fit in a cradle so it can be used as a fixed head or can be hand-held?

Comment: @JimStewart, the sprayer can be handheld but it can also fit in the bracket and used as a fixed head.

Comment: Is it leaking at the bottom of the nut when the shower is on or only right after the shower is turned off?

Comment: @JimStewart, yes, it's leaking at the bottom of the nut when the shower is on.  When it's off, there's no leaking.

Comment: You should be able to get washer seals for that. I think the perforated disc is a flow restrictor to limit the flow to a set amount, usually given in small print on the face of the head. Maybe the flow restrictor also acted as a seal but got compressed over time.

Answer (score 2):

The black magic is the Teflon tape. NPT threaded pipes and hoses are probably what you’ve got for the shower fixture and NPT threads don’t deform as they are tightened to make a seal.

So you would usually see a rubber washer OR you would use Teflon tape. If it’s leaking and there’s no washer, you should put new Teflon tape on the threads and that should hopefully take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question.  So, it's not leaking where the threads are.  I don't know how to explain without a video but the nut is cone shaped.  Where it's leaking/dripping is at the bottom of the cone.  I think normally, if there's a rubber washer, the washer would prevent this drip but the funny thing is I don't remember it leaking for the last 4-5 years until now and it has no washer which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: @Classified post a photo to help us see. Sometimes a valve fails and starts leaking after years of use. It’s possible it’s just got a part inside that’s worn out.

Comment: Thanks again for continuing to try to help me.  I posted some photos but I can take more if these are not clear.  I tried to annotate where the leak is coming from.  Hopefully it's clear enough.